# Trouble creating a canvas to draw signature on Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, signature, angular8

I'm trying to create a component to sign with HTML 5 and canvas in Angular 8, I need the component to recognize touch events as well as mouse events.

I've been taking inspiration from this page to create the component, since it's something very similar to what I need:

https://kernhanda.github.io/tutorial-typescript-canvas-drawing/

But I haven't been able to make the component work, I don't know why, I think the error may be due to the fact that I do not have the same configuration of the `tsconfig.json` file as the tutorial.

This is the configuration of the `tsconfig.json` file from the tutorial

[image: Conf]

And this is mine:

[image: Conf]

So I've come to a point where I don't know how to move forward, please if anyone knows exactly what I'm doing wrong or if there's a simpler way to create the component for the signature that recognizes touch events I'd be very grateful if you would tell me.

**EDIT**: I share a stackblitz with the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szrn6z

**EDIT**: The code works on Stackblitz but not in my project, this could be because of the tsconfig.json file configuration?

Comment: Can you share a Stackblitz?

Comment: Added, sorry I forgot

Comment: Your Stackblitz seems to work. I tried to change the `@ViewChild` to ` @ViewChild("canvas", { static: true }) public canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;` and so you can use it in the on init method like `this.canvasEl = this.canvas.nativeElement;`. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2br2i4?file=src/app/signature.component.ts). Do you get some errors?

Comment: I have changed it and I receive no error, but it's not working. Could it be because of the tsconfig.json file that I said? Because on the stackblittz works perfectly and in my project not, doesn't make sense.

Comment: If someone wants to try a different, working, code base for the same purpose, then I leave this link here https://gist.github.com/anupkrbid/6447d97df6be6761d394f18895bc680d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally and if it helps someone, the code was fine, it didn't "work" in my project because I wasn't taking the X and Y coordinates properly, so I had to manage to get it, using this code:

```
let r = this.canvasEl.getBoundingClientRect();
let mouseX;
if((e as TouchEvent).changedTouches) {
     mouseX = (e as TouchEvent).changedTouches[0].pageX - r.left;
} else {
     mouseX = (e as MouseEvent).layerX;
}

let mouseY;
if((e as TouchEvent).changedTouches) {
     mouseY = (e as TouchEvent).changedTouches[0].pageY - r.top;
} else {
     mouseY = (e as MouseEvent).layerY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I also had to change layerX to offsetX  (and Y). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340676/how-can-i-set-an-event-type-for-layerx-and-layery