# How can I set an Event type for 'layerX' and 'layerY'

Tags: typescript, types, addeventlistener

I'm making a dropdown menu having an absolute position.
It gets x, y coordiation from mouse event.

```js
container.addEventListener(
  'contextmenu',
    (e: MouseEvent) => {
      drawingMenuX = e.layerX + 15; // chartiq basic padding is 15
      drawingMenuY = e.layerY + 15;
    },
    false,
);
```

But it show error "Property 'layerX' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'.ts(2339)".
How can I set a correct event type instead of MouseEvent?

Comment: aparently the layer* properties are non standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX

Comment: thanks, @DanielA.White. Do you know which one is the alternative?

Answer (score 6):

As above @Daniel A.White said, it because layerX and layerY are non-standard. The alternative option is offsetX and offsetY.

Comment: Not necessarily. offsetX/offsetY are the position of the mouse relatively to the "closest positioned element", i.e. an element whose position style property is not static. That's not the target element if it's statically positioned.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23217491/4162023